Flask images on render not displaying
I have a Flask application on render, I am using the render persistent disk (/var/static/uploads) to store uploaded images, the images are uploaded, but I have problem rendering them on the html template.
def save_image(image_data):
   
    filename = generate_unique_filename(image_data.filename)
    
    static_uploads_folder = os.path.join('/var/static/uploads')
   
    image_data.save(os.path.join(static_uploads_folder, filename))
   
    return filename


def generate_unique_filename(original_filename):
    filename, extension = os.path.splitext(original_filename)
    timestamp = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    unique_filename = f"{secure_filename(filename)}_{timestamp}{extension}"
    return unique_filename

template
  <div class="row row-cols-2 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-lg-4">
      {% for product in products %}
      <div class="col">
          <div class="card product-card border-0">
              <div class="magnifier position-relative overflow-hidden">
                  {% if product.cover_image %}
                  <img src="/static/uploads/{{ product.cover_image }}" class="card-img-top product-image" alt="{{ product.name }}">
                  {% else %}
                  <img src="/static/path_to_default_image.jpg" class="card-img-top product-image" alt="{{ product.name }}">
                  {% endif %}
              </div>

              <div class="card-body text-center">
                  <h6 class="card-title text-primary mb-2">{{ product.brand }}</h6>
                  <p class="card-text text-muted fs-6 mb-3">{{ product.description | truncate(120) }}</p>
                  <p class="card-text fs-6 mb-2"><strong>Ksh {{ product.unit_price }} </strong></p>

                  <!-- Add to Cart Button -->
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm fs-6" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#addToCartModal{{ product.id }}">
                       Buy
                  </button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
  </div>

           

I have also configured the static folder I don't know what am doing wrong
 app.static_folder = '/var/static/uploads'
I created the static folder uploaded the images to persistent disk /var/static/uploads successfully, now I am having problems retrieving the images.
render@srv-cnn0go8cmk4c73ak6cf0-0:~/project/src$ cd /
render@srv-cnn0go8cmk4c73ak6cf0-0:/$ ls var/static/uploads
1000213051_20240429222907.png                   PhotoRoom-20240123_105100_5_20240429214709.png
1000216424_20240429211503.jpg                   PhotoRoom-20240123_105100_6_20240429214709.png
1000216434_20240429211503.jpg                   PhotoRoom-20240123_105100_7_20240429214709.png
1000216446_20240429211503.jpg                   PhotoRoom-20240123_105101_9_20240429222907.png
1000217105_20240429211503.jpg                   PhotoRoom-20240123_105102_10_20240429222907.png
PhotoRoom-20240112_080418_20240429224147.png    PhotoRoom-20240123_114305_3_20240429223934.png
PhotoRoom-20240114_081108_20240429224147.png    PhotoRoom-20240312_191315_20240429223357.png
PhotoRoom-20240114_082716_20240429224147.png    PhotoRoom-20240312_192344_1_20240429223357.png
PhotoRoom-20240114_104057_2_20240429223934.png  PhotoRoom-20240312_192344_3_20240429223635.png
PhotoRoom-20240123_105059_2_20240429214709.png


I have named my persistent disk on render as /var/static/uploads.

Your template call <img src="/static/uploads/{{ product.cover_image }}", while your static folder is defined as app.static_folder = '/var/static/uploads'.
Consider using src="{{ url_for('static', filename=filename) }}" and see if things improve. Make sure to add from flask import url_for in your views.py

I have adjusted the code according to your suggestion.     I think it points to the correct path [link] (https://nourishagroceries.onrender.com/static/uploads/PhotoRoom-20240123_105059_1_20240505072528.png)  but the image is rendered on the HTML temlate

If I understand your template correctly, static/uploads is already marked as a static path. So, you should probably have src="{{ url_for('static', filename=product_images[0].cover_image) }}". If the path is correct, the image should be displayed, unless there are issues with the <div class="magnifier position-relative overflow-hidden">.

My persistent disk was mounted on the root folder,  I had to change the location of my persistent disk from /var/static/uploads to the same folder where the project is saved for my case its /opt/render/projects/apps/static/uploads removed the static folder and everything is working fine, Thanks
